# "Could off" as opposed to "could have"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I myself am not a native speaker and my english therefore is likely not the best. I recently noticed a trend of people using the phrase "Could off done X". Which irritates me a lot. This has become so frequent, that I am starting to doubt myself and think whether I am wrong here. Other people on the internet don't seem to me as irritated, as I have not found anyone complaining about it (neither on ELL). Please help me out here:

> It is "*could have done*" and **never** "*could off done*", right?

Comment: This phrase (normally spelt with *of* instead of *off*, but that doesn't make it any better) has been around for at least several decades, and likely started with a mistranscription of *could've*.

Comment: Soo it is wrong and I am sane?

Comment: I'm fairly confident any competent English teacher would mark it down. Sanity is another issue altogether. :)

Comment: By the way, it's "as opposed to" (see your question's title) - hopefully, this is not the start of a new mistranscription. :)

Comment: It's wrong and  a person with good high school education should be able to spot it. Could've, should've, might've, would've. That said, it is a spoken form used  in dialogues or speech. Not a written form.

Comment: Most competent native English speaker would say it without noticing.Many otherwise competent English speakers and learners have been seduced by the zombie rule that claims **off of** is ungrammatical, in situations where _off_ by itself is grammatical. This is nonsense. Sorry. Live and learn; it's **your** language and you can do what you want in it. If anybody ever tries to correct you, though, feel free to laugh in their fact.

Comment: The comment above does not address the use of _of_ instead of _have_ in the contraction. That is explained easily, because _could've_ and _could of_ are identical in pronunciation, and a produce of speech, not writing, so there is precise spelling available, and people will hear what they hear.

Comment: Not an _exact_ duplicate. _Could off_ as opposed to _could of_ as a phonetic spelling of _could have/could have_ is worth its own question.